# How do I switch views in cocoa touch?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uikit, uistoryboard

I have two view controllers named "view1ViewController" and "view2ViewController" in an cocoa touch project, and they are both linked to a UIView in the storyboard.  Say I put a button in view1.  Codewise, what's the easiest way to switch to view2 after I press that button?  What code should I need to type to get this to work?

-- Update --

Despite what you have all told me about this, I still can't get this to work.  Maybe I'm not getting something?  Do I need to add something else?  Here is the code for **view1ViewController.m**:

```
#import "view1ViewController.h"
#import "view2ViewController.h"


@interface view1ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) view2ViewController *controller;

@end

@implementation view1ViewController
@synthesize controller = _controller;

- (view2ViewController *)controller
{
    if (!_controller) {
        _controller = [[view2ViewController alloc] init];
    }
    return _controller;
}

- (IBAction)buttonPressed {
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.controller animated:YES];
}
@end
```

I haven't touched the other files and made sure to set the class of the added view in the storyboard to view2ViewController.

Comment: Xcode is just an IDE – so the correct answer would be: not at all

Comment: Do you have to do it in code, or would a segue-based approach work for you?

Comment: I don't really like a segue-based approach because I am trying to develop an app that takes a rather dynamic approach to a view,

Comment: It's possible there's a bunch of different stuff you have to do to handle storyboards. If you're not going to use storyboards, I would suggest creating a project that uses interface builder xib files instead. I don't know much about storyboards so I can't be much help there. For a (hopefully) quick fix, you can trigger a segue programatically. Can you edit the answer and paste in the complete error message?

Comment: If you're using UIView, you're not using Cocoa, you're using Cocoa Touch. I've edited your question accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:view2ViewController animated:YES];
```

simple result you could be able to find yourself just googling a while...

I assumed your app is navigation-based. If this is not the case, you'll need to init a `UINavigationController`. For example in your app delegate, in your `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method, you may do something like

```
navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
[self.window addSubview:navigationController.view];
[navigationController pushViewController:self.viewController animated:NO];

[self.window addSubview:navigationController.view];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

where `navigationController` is a `UINavigationController` set as `@property`.

If you do not want to setup a `UINavigationController` you may chose to present the other view modally using

```
[self presentModalViewController:view2ViewController animated:YES];
```

Comment: do I have to #import anything in any files?  because it says unexpected inference name "view2ViewController"

Comment: You have to #import the header file for view2ViewController in whatever file you want to reference it from. Also remember that if you're not using ARC, you'll want to release your view2viewcontroller: View2ViewController *controller = [[View2ViewController alloc] init]; [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES]; [controller release];

Comment: It's still not working.  Can you read my update in the main post?  Your comment was very helpful BTW, Jack!

Comment: Hmmm. Well off the bat I see that you're defining a custom getter method for controller. You don't need that method (- (view2ViewController *)controller). I don't think that's what's wrong though.

Comment: Does xcode automatically assume that "controller" is a subclass of UIViewController?

Comment: Also, this isn't a navigation view.  This is a blank view.

Comment: Of course you must specify that it's a subclass of `UIViewController` in the definition of your interface. Besides, I edited the post adding some information about the navigation controller.

Answer (score 1):

If you have not setup a navigation controller, this approach will not work. To setup the navigation controller, you need to make sure that the current view is the root view controller for the navigation controller. This can be done programmatically, but if your using the Storyboard it would be much easier to embed the view in a navigation controller. Once the controller is in place, the pushing should work.

For the Storyboard embedding, go to the top menu and choose 
**Edit->Embed in Navigation Controller.**

For doing it through the code, wherever you create this view, instead write it as

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:view1ViewController];
```

Then add the navigation controller wherever you added the view1ViewController.